# Cannot bind after unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to bind a click event after previously unbinding it and I cannot get it to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1" style="width: 100px; vertical-align: middle" />
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="dp1Icon" style="outline-style:none"><img src="<%=context%>/images/calendar-glyph.png"></span>
</div>
```

The input is actually a bootstrap datepicker component. The span contains a bootstrap glyph that triggers the datepicker to open. I have a radio button group that toggles disabling these like this:

```
$(".date-wrap input[type='radio']").on("click", function(e){

        if ($(e.target).val() == "permanent"){
            $("#dp1, #dp1Icon").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#dp1Icon").unbind("click"); // Disabled attribute only works on form controls, not spans. So we have to unbind the event
            $("#dp1").removeAttr("readonly", "readonly");
        }else{
            $("#dp1, #dp1Icon, #e3").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#dp1Icon").bind("click");
            $("#dp1").removeAttr("readonly");
        }
    });
```

So, if the value of the radio button they click is "permanent", everything becomes disabled; that works great. Otherwise, I attempt to turn them back on.

The only thing I can think of is that when I try to bind the click event to the glyphicon again, I must define the actual handler that opens the datepicker; like this:

```
$("#dp1Icon").bind("click", $("#dp1").datepicker('show'));
```

But all that does is open the datepicker as soon as I click the other radio button. I want it to open only when they click it. 
What important piece am I missing here? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `bind()` needs a handler argument. Read the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind("click")` does not magically re-add the event. You need to add it back the event.

```
$("#dp1Icon").on("click", function(){ $("#dp1").datepicker('show'); } );
```

You might be better off just setting a flag inside that function and not removing the event.

Comment: Thank you, very quick and helpful.